# LoadLibrary fails; GetLastError no help

Tags: visual-c++, loadlibrary

I have a project that I converted from Visual Studio 2003 .NET  to Visual Studio 2010.  It's NOT a .NET project; it's Visual C++ (unmanaged).

The DLL pulls in additional DLLs.  If I link an executable with this DLL, then the executable dies during the initialization of the DLL.  (I can tell, there are constructors for static objects that are being called, and I can see their operation.)  I've removed ALL VS 2010-created DLLs from my path, except for one of them, which causes the error.  Replacing that one with the VS.NET-created version allows the program to run.

Since I'm not getting any useful information, I decided to write a test application that doesn't directly link to the DLL, but instead uses LoadLibrary to load the library.  The idea was that I could use GetLastError() to help figure the issue with the library.  No go; I get an error code -529697949, which isn't a Windows error code at all!  (If I change the DLL to the VS.NET-created version, the program loads the DLL properly.)

I used the Dependency Walker (www.dependencywalker.com) to check the DLL, and it tells me that "At least one delay-load dependency module was not found," highlighting IESHIMS.DLL and WER.DLL.  I am seeing no other error with that tool.  Running it on the VS.NET-created DLL shows the same two warnings, so I figure this is a red herring.

```
static void showMessage(const wchar_t *wmsg)
{
        std::wcout << wmsg << std::endl;
        ::MessageBox(NULL, wmsg, TEXT("Message"), MB_OK);
}

static void testLoadLibrary(const wchar_t *lib)
{
        ::SetLastError(0L);
        ::SetErrorMode(0);

        std::wstringstream wss;

        wss << "LoadLibrary: " << lib;
        showMessage(wss.str().c_str());
        HINSTANCE LoadME = ::AfxLoadLibrary(lib);
        if (LoadME == NULL) {
                DWORD dw = ::GetLastError();
                wss << "Failed: Error code " << dw;
                showMessage(wss.str().c_str());
                ErrorExit(lib, dw);
        } else {
                wss << "LoadLibrary of " << lib << " succeeded.";
                showMessage(wss.str().c_str());
                ::FreeLibrary(LoadME);
        }
}
```

Finally, I ran Process Monitor (sysinternals.com) to monitor the test program, looking at all entries with Path containing the string "dll."  I don't see anything particularly informative in this list--no idea why the DLL is failing to load.

If I use LoadLibraryEx with DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES, the library loads, so this really looks like a dependency issue, which is why I'm surprised that the dependency walker isn't being particularly helpful.

I've tried this on Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 2003; same behavior.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an OS tool to help diagnose problems like this. Download the SDK or DDK and use gflags.exe to set 'Show Loader Snaps' (+sls) for the process. That should reveal why the DLL load fails.

The loader snaps output will appear in the debugger output window.

Martyn

Comment: Thank you for the help.  It isolated my DLL as the issue, but didn't explain WHY.  It appears that a class definition derived from CWinApp is probably the culprint; I'm not sure why it was included in the DLL, and removing the .cpp from the project allows the library to load without error.

Comment: Is the project MFC-based? Is the relevant MFC dll installed? Did you mix debug and release compiled stuff?