# How to check for DLL dependency?

Tags: windows, dll, dependencies

Sometimes when I'm doing a little project I'm not careful enough and accidentally add a dependency for a DLL that I am not aware of. When I ship this program to a friend or other people, "it doesn't work"  because "some DLL" is missing. This is of course because the program can find the DLL on my system, but not on theirs.

Is there a way to scan an executable for DLL dependencies or execute the program in a "clean" DLL-free environment for testing to prevent these *oops* situations?

Comment: The debugger shows every DLL that gets loaded in the Output window.  The Debug + Windows + Modules shows a list of them.  Be sure that you can account for all of them.  And test your installer like you test your code, use a VM.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Can I find a full list of standard windows DLL's somewhere?

Comment: Yup, in c:\windows\system32 with a Microsoft copyright.

Comment: @orlp - You might also try `dumpbin /dependents <program>`. I'm guessing the list will be more relevant than listing all DLLs in `%SYSTEM%` or `%SYSTEM32%`. Also see [DUMPBIN Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756as972.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Check [\[SO\]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74883130/4788546) for a comprehensive answer (console oriented).

Answer (score 333):

`dumpbin` from Visual Studio tools (VC\bin folder) can help here:

```
dumpbin /dependents your_dll_file.dll
```

Comment: Handy little tool, and saves having to install anything new when you already have VS installed.

Comment: Yes, `dumpbin.exe` is very useful to figure out `/dependents` and `/imports`. You can also use it on other machines if you copy `link.exe` along with it and make sure the corresponding [x86 Visual C++ Runtime Redistributable (`msvcr120.dll` for Visual Studio 2013)](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=40784) is available on the target machine. Some options have additional dependencies. - By the way, they screwed up the option name, it should have been `/PREREQUISITES` rather than `/DEPENDENTS`, they should have studied Latin.

Comment: If you get an error message with `mspdb110.dll not found`, try launching the 64 version instead `VC\bin\amd64\dumpbin.exe` before re-installing Visual Studio ;)

Comment: It's so great, we added this into our build system as a verification step when the final executable is generated so we don't depend on something that is not included in the shipping.

Comment: The only drawback is this handy tool is very hidden: c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\Hostx64\x64>dumpbin

Comment: `dumpbin` only lists DLLs but doesn't check for their presence.

Comment: For VS2017 or VS2019 this answer works perfectly well to ensure `dumpbin` is available on your machine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50710182/4625433

Comment: @rkachach If you open the Visual Studio command line (Tools -> Visual Studio Command Prompt) this is recognized as an external command and you only need to type "dumpbin".

Comment: @JeffRSon this didn't work for my DLL. I know the tensorflow.dll I downloaded epends upon a cuda DLL. It displays an error stating such when I run the program. However the dumpbin command does not list any cuda DLLS as a dependency.

Comment: Well, that's probably because the tensorflow dll loads this cuda dll via LoadLibrary. Such dependencies cannot be detected.

Comment: @rkachach just open start menu, type "dev" and open Developer Command Prompt (which is the same as Tools > Visual Studio Command Prompt in VS), or run vcvarsall.bat manually

Comment: This is the best answer for me!

Comment: @JeffRSon `ldd` (see the answer below this one) detects recursive DLL dependencies just fine.

Comment: "The code execution cannot proceed because mspdb110.dll was not found"... the project builds fine on another machine... just kill me.

Comment: it seems like dumpbin would need to be combined with some other scripting in order to identify missing DLLs ?

Comment: For me it was in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\SDK\ScopeCppSDK\vc15\VC\bin

Comment: I will buy you a beer, any time. Thank you amigo!!!!

Answer (score 94):

I can recommend interesting solution for Linux fans. After I explored this solution, I've switched from DependencyWalker to this.

You can use your favorite [`ldd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) over Windows-related `exe`, `dll`.

To do this you need to install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) (basic installation, without additional packages required) on your Windows and then just start `Cygwin Terminal`. Now you can run your favorite Linux commands, including:

```
$ ldd your_dll_file.dll
```

**UPD:** You can use `ldd` also through [git bash terminal on Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/index.html). No need to install cygwin in case if you have git already installed.

Comment: I just install the cygwin and was happy to find back linux commands, but I could not get out of the Cygwin root to acces other files on my local drive (C:). Is that normal?

Comment: I think this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850920/how-to-navigate-to-a-directory-in-c-with-cygwin

Comment: Unfortunately, there are some dependencies that are not found this way: `$ ldd ./Debug/helloworld.exe ??? => ??? (0x77d60000)`. The utility dumpbin shows all dependencies correctly.

Comment: I use ldd through GIT BASH terminal on windows and works fine. So if you have git it wil be easy, no need to install cygwin.

Example:
borkox@bobipc MINGW64 ~
$ ldd /c/Users/borkox/.javacpp/cache/openblas-0.3.0-1.4.2-windows-x86_64.jar/org/bytedeco/javacpp/windows-x86_64/jniopenblas_nolapack.dll
        ntdll.dll => /c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ffe46910000)
        KERNEL32.DLL => /c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ffe46610000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ffe42d40000)
        msvcrt.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/msvcrt.dll (0x7ffe44120000)

Comment: As someone who already had git bash installed, this was a preferable solution. Thank you!

Comment: you can use "strace yourprogram" to see which dll you need

Answer (score 45):

1. Figure out the full file path to the assembly you're trying to work with
2. Press the start button, type "dev". Launch the program called "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017"
3. In the window that opens, type `dumpbin /dependents [path]`, where `[path]` is the path you figured out in step 1
4. press the enter key

Bam, you've got your dependency information. The window should look like this:

[image]

**Update for VS 2019:** you need this package in your VS installation: [image]

Comment: "Bam" all you want, but I don't find `dumpbin` all that useful, because it isn't recursive. If any DLL dependency in turn depends on a DLL not already among the list of direct dependencies, you're still screwed. Better to use a tool that isn't half-assed, such as `ldd`.

Answer (score 24):

Try [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) it is described as "An open-source modern Dependency Walker".

It has a GUI but it also works from the command line with optional JSON output!

To display recursively the dependencies of mydll.dll up to a depth of 1:

```
Dependencies.exe -chain mydll.dll -depth 1
```

Example of output:

```
  □ mydll.dll (ROOT) : C:/.../mydll.dll
|  □ USER32.dll (WellKnownDlls) : C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\user32.dll
|  □ ADVAPI32.dll (WellKnownDlls) : C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll
|  □ ole32.dll (WellKnownDlls) : C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ole32.dll
|  □ GDI32.dll (WellKnownDlls) : C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll
|  □ CRYPT32.dll (WellKnownDlls) : C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CRYPT32.dll
|  □ Secur32.dll (WindowsFolder) : C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\Secur32.dll
|  □ MSVCP140D.dll (WindowsFolder) : C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MSVCP140D.dll
|  □ USP10.dll (WindowsFolder) : C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\USP10.dll
|  □ KERNEL32.dll (WellKnownDlls) : C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
|  □ VCRUNTIME140D.dll (WindowsFolder) : C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\VCRUNTIME140D.dll
|  □ ucrtbased.dll (WindowsFolder) : C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll
```

If a DLL is missing (at any depth) the output is similar to:

```
├ mydll.dll (ROOT) : other.dll
|  ├ other.dll (NOT_FOUND) :
```

Note that it may take a long time to produce a result if the maximum dependency depth is deep.

Comment: Nice tool, without having Cygwin or Visual Studio Runtime installed. Thank you for sharing!

Comment: will the tool also indicate on output what DLL is missing ?
how is this indicated on the output (of this great tool) the DLL being missing on the system it runs on ? I'm trying to debug docker container with this tool...

Comment: @IdanB I have just tested and yes the output is clear on a missing DLL, see my edited answer. Good luck with your debugging.

Answer (score 10):

1. There is a program called "Depends"
2. If you have cygwin installed, nothing simpler then ldd file.exe

Comment: The tool is called *Dependency Walker*; it's executable image is named *depends.exe*.

Comment: Dependency Walker is dated. Its last built is in 2008!

Comment: `depends` doesn't support API sets so it's useless for Win7+.

Comment: For a modern alternative to "Depends" see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72189765/4669135)

Answer (score 10):

The safest thing is have some clean virtual machine, on which you can test your program. On every version you'd like to test, restore the VM to its initial clean value. Then install your program using its setup, and see if it works.

Dll problems have different faces. If you use Visual Studio and dynamically link to the CRT, you have to distribute the CRT DLLs. Update your VS, and you have to distribute another version of the CRT. Just checking dependencies is not enough, as you might miss those. Doing a full install on a clean machine is the only safe solution, IMO.

If you don't want to setup a full-blown test environment and have Windows 7, you can use XP-Mode as the initial clean machine, and [XP-More](http://xpmore.codeplex.com/) to duplicate the VM.

Answer (score 7):

On your development machine, you can execute the program and run [Sysinternals Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx). In the lower pane, it will show you the loaded DLLs and the current paths to them which is handy for a number of reasons. If you are executing off your deployment package, it would reveal which DLLs are referenced in the wrong path (i.e. weren't packaged correctly).

Currently, our company uses Visual Studio Installer projects to walk the dependency tree and output as loose files the program. In VS2013, this is now an extension: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d. We then package these loose files in a more comprehensive installer but at least that setup project all the dot net dependencies and drops them into the one spot and warns you when things are missing.

Answer (score 5):

NDepend was already mentioned by Jesse (if you analyze .NET code) but let's explain exactly how it can help.

> Is there a program/script that can scan an executable for DLL
> dependencies or execute the program in a "clean" DLL-free environment
> for testing to prevent these oops situations?

In the NDepend Project Properties panel, you can define what application assemblies to analyze (in green) and **NDepend will infer Third-Party assemblies used by application ones** (in blue). A list of directories where to search application and third-party assemblies is provided.

[image: NDepend Project Properties Application and Third-Party assemblies]

If a third-party assembly is not found in these directories, it will be in error mode. For example, if I remove the .NET Fx directory `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`, I can see that .NET Fx third-party assemblies are not resolved:

[image: NDepend Project Properties Application and Third-Party assemblies not resolved]

*Disclaimer: I work for NDepend*

Answer (score 3):

In the past (i.e. WinXP days), I used to depend/rely on DLL Dependency Walker (depends.exe) but there are times when I am still not able to determine the DLL issue(s).  Ideally, we'd like to find out before runtime by inspections but if that does not resolve it (or taking too much time), you can try enabling the "loader snap" as described on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/11/20/debugging-loadlibrary-failures.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556886(v=vs.85).aspx and briefly mentioned [LoadLibrary fails; GetLastError no help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154600/loadlibrary-fails-getlasterror-no-help/6154709#6154709)

WARNING: I've messed up my Windows in the past fooling around with gflag making it crawl to its knees, you have been forewarned.

[image]

Note: "Loader snap" is per-process so the UI enable won't stay checked (use cdb or glfags -i)

Answer (score 2):

Please refer SysInternal toolkit from Microsoft from below link,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Goto the download folder, Open "Procexp64.exe" as admin privilege.
Open Find Menu-> "Find Handle or DLL" option or Ctrl+F shortcut way.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Was the DLL compiled in "Debug Mode" and then deployed?

If so, it may depend on "D" versions of DLLs.  For example:

```
  MSVCP140D.dll
  VCRUNTIME140D.dll
```

These would not be dependents if the DLL is built in "Release Mode."  The D versions do not come with the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables.

To see if that is the case, as others have pointed out:

From Visual Studio: Tools -> Visual Studio Command Prompt.

In the command prompt run `dumpbin /dependents` against the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

To view ".dll" dependencies and other useful information in Windows - i can highly recommend the CFF Explorer (https://ntcore.com/?page_id=388) its free and very useful. You can view "import" and "export" dependencies of the ".dll" file and many other functions. And it comes with a GUI - so you dont have to use the cli ...