# Detecting the MSC_VER of a lib

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, static-libraries, redistributable

I have a code base that I am compiling in to a library. Normally I would send the library as `MSVC++ 10.0 _MSC_VER == 1600 (Visual Studio 2010)` but my customer is asking for it as `MSVC++ 11.0 _MSC_VER == 1700 (Visual Studio 2012)`.

I have downloaded/installed and compiled new versions of my lib with Visual Studio 2012. Now I want to check the lib to see what `_MSC_VER` version it is currently using to ensure that I am sending them the correct version.

How do you detect what `_MSC_VER` is used in a library?

Comment: Write a little test program that uses a function in your .lib.  Link it with the *old* version of your .lib and verify that you get the linker error that your customer gets.  Now link it with your *new* version and verify that you don't get a linker error.

Comment: @HansPassant There must be a tool to be able to detect the _MSC_VER of a library. Making a application specific to my lib to detect the _MSC_VER seems like a hack to me.

Comment: Yes, that tool is called "linker".  It is the one that generates the error.  You can use notepad.exe if you really want to.  Search for FAILIFMISMATCH.  You'll find them in your old .lib

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be able to try dumpbin.

```
c:\dev\tagainijisho>dumpbin C:\Qt\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\lib\qtmaind.lib /rawdata | find "_MSC_VER"
  00000040: 3A 22 5F 4D 53 43 5F 56 45 52 3D 31 36 30 30 22  :"_MSC_VER=1600"
```

Answer (score 0):

`_MSC_VER` is a macro which only exists in LIB or OBJ files for determining linking capabilities, so **you can't use `dumpbin PEfile /rawdata | find "_MSC_VER"` for *compiled* EXE or DLL files**. In that case you need to [check the dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7378959/995714) by running

```
dumpbin /dependents PEfile
```

Look for the `MSVC*.dll` or `VCRUNTIME*.dll` in the dependency list. The number after that is the VC redistributable version

```
PS C:> dumpbin.exe /dependents C:\qpdf17.dll
[...]
  Image has the following dependencies:

    ADVAPI32.dll
    MSVCP120.dll
    MSVCR120.dll
    KERNEL32.dll

[...]
PS C:> dumpbin.exe /dependents C:\qpdf26.dll
[...]
  Image has the following dependencies:

    ADVAPI32.dll
    MSVCP140.dll
    KERNEL32.dll
    VCRUNTIME140.dll
    VCRUNTIME140_1.dll
[...]
PS C:>
```

In the above example **MSVCP120** is from MSVC++ 12.0 which means Visual Studio 2013 and `_MSC_VER=1800`. Similarly **VCRUNTIME140** is from MSVC++ 14.0 which means Visual Studio 2015 and `_MSC_VER=1900`. You can check the version and `_MSC_VER` values [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#Internal_version_numbering)

---

Sometimes the `/rawdata` option won't even work on LIB or OBJ files. I redirected the output to file and saw that the output is truncated in the middle for some unknown reason.  The `/dependents` option also doesn't work for them. In that case you need to use another way. If you have GNU tools then you can run either of the below

```powershell
strings OBJ_or_LIB.file | grep -Po '_MSC_VER=\d+'
grep -aPo '_MSC_VER=\d+' OBJ_or_LIB.file
```

Or you can also use this PowerShell command

```powershell
sls -Ca '_MSC_VER=\d+' OBJ_or_LIB.file |% {$_.matches} | select value
```

or the full command:

```powershell
Select-String -CaseSensitive '_MSC_VER=\d+' OBJ_or_LIB.file |
    ForEach-Object {$_.matches} |
    Select-Object value
```