# Can't get managed C++ assembly to work on Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, managed-c++

I am trying to compile a project ([NBIS.Net 5.0.0](https://www.nist.gov/programs-projects/biometrics-web-services-bws)) into a `.dll` so I can add it as reference in another .NET C# project (VS 2013).
Everything works fine, my program runs and uses functions from the referenced library. This is on the dev machine (win7 x64) as well as on a target machine (win7 x64).

But when I try to run it on a Surface Pro 4 with Windows 10, my Application crashes as soon as it starts using a function of that particualr assembly.
Is there any setting that I need to change when I compile the assembly with VS?
Or are there runtimes missing on the Windows 10 target machine that are present on a Windows 7 machine?
Thank you!

Comment: possible reasons include the two you mentioned, and probably 100 more. do you have a crashdump available, or can you attach a remote debuger to the release environment?

Comment: Put try/catch around that particular call and read the exception. You may be missing VS redistributables.

Comment: I attached a remote debugger on the process and was able to get the `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`: "Could not load file or assembly 'NBIS.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found: NBIS.dll" This .dll exists in the same folder as the exe AND also in a path that is in the PATH environment variable. How can I find out what dependency it its that it can not find? Thanks!

Comment: It's probably VCredist. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378959/how-to-check-for-dll-dependency/28304716#28304716

Comment: I did not install the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package. That was the trouble...

Comment: I face issues compiling NBIS on Windows to use it from C#. Could you share your steps or maybe even compiled version? dejan.mauer at gmail.com

Answer (score -1):

To troubleshoot this kind of problem, you can use Fusion. It's .NET's assembly binding logging tool.

Scott Hanselman has a [Blog Post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) on using it and related tools.