# FileNotFoundException - which dependency can't it find?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am receiving this exception in my C# project:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'wcl.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.`

`wcl.dll` is present, so I can only think that the exception is caused by one of its dependencies, which must be missing.

Is there any way to tell what file could not be found?

**Edit**

I don't have access to the source code or anything from `wcl.dll` - it's a third-party library.

**Another edit**

This exception only shows up when I run the application on a clean VM (Win 7, 64 bit), but not on other devices such as my own development PC (also Win 7, 64 bit)

**Edited** again to change to the actual dll file name!

**Update**

Hmm... So I found out the two missing dlls by using `dumpbin /dependencies`.  The exception goes away if I include msvcp110.dll and msvcr110.dll copy these into the running directory of the application. However, if I copy them into C:\Windows\System32 it doesn't!

But this problem is only on the Virtual Machine - on any other computer, it suffices to have them in C:\Windows\System32. I have read that these are part of Visual C++ Redistributable - do I have to make that a prerequisite of my project? (Though not sure if that will help with my VM problem)

Comment: Does blah.dll by any chance has referenced Embedded Assemblies? If yes, you have to load the embedded assemblies into your appdomain in order to use that dll

Comment: The way to tell is by enabling fusion logging. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net

Comment: Is your framework aligned with the framework of blah.dll?

Comment: Are `blah` dependencies referenced well ? you should know about all `blah` dependencies and add them also.

Comment: as a hint: [how-to-check-for-dll-dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378959/how-to-check-for-dll-dependency)

Comment: @Ryfang - thanks for that, `dumpbin` - suggested in that link - did help in that it revealed two missing dlls from C:\Windows\System32 - I copied them to the offending machine, but I'm still getting the same exception.