# How to find which DLLs are missing?

Tags: windows, dll

Let's say I'm doing something a bit obscure - I'm manually using some VC utility, which depends on some DLL (in my case mspdbcore.dll), but this DLL doesn't load, because it probably depends on yet another DLL, which isn't in the PATH. How can I find all the DLLs this one is missing, or at least all this one depends on?

Comment: Can you give us more specific information, including any error messages?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378959/how-to-check-for-dll-dependency

Comment: I'm afraid the only error message is that "it cannot load". I checked the other thread, but the recommended utility only creates a huge list of symbols and says that something failed, the VC utility fails too, just saying "it cannot load".

Comment: You are asking for somebody to write you a manual instead of providing you with the solution.  Nobody will write one since the solution is so simple.  Always run VS tools from the Developer Command Prompt, it ensures that the PATH is configured correctly.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for the Linux equivalent of ldd.