# OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found importing mxnet in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, mxnet

I am using Pycharm, importing `mxnet` to the project

I think I meet a file loss error but I could not find the solution

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/E/ZJL_Test_package/ZJL_Test/feature/extract_image.py", line 1, in <module>
from mxnet import nd, image
  File "C:\D\Programs\Python37\lib\site-packages\mxnet\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
from . import engine
  File "C:\D\Programs\Python37\lib\site-packages\mxnet\engine.py", line 23, in <module>
from .base import _LIB, check_call
  File "C:\D\Programs\Python37\lib\site-packages\mxnet\base.py", line 113, in <module>
    _LIB = _load_lib()
  File "C:\D\Programs\Python37\lib\site-packages\mxnet\base.py", line 105, in _load_lib
lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_path[0], ctypes.RTLD_LOCAL)
  File "C:\D\Programs\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

The version of Pycharm and Python are both the up to date(the latest), with 64-bit windows 10 and 64-bit Python, 64-bit PyCharm

This problem seems disappear after I restart the computer and open PyCharm again. I did nothing else... So if anyone could explain this, please give your answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/1740

- First, try using Anaconda (recommended) as per: http://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/install/index.html?platform=Windows&language=Python&processor=CPU
- You may need to upgrade to 64 bit python: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/
- You may need to install the right version of Cuda - use dumpbin to check the DLL dependency as per: [How to check for DLL dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378959/how-to-check-for-dll-dependency/28304716#28304716) (Dumpbin comes with visual studio).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems my problem does not match. By the way the problem go away now but I still do not find the reason