# Problem running PyPy3 on Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: pypy

I'm trying to run PyPy3 on Windows 10 Enterprise (with the VC++ redistributables for 2008, 2013, and 2015). PyPy2.7 7.1.1 runs with no problems. However, both PyPy3.6 v7.1.1-beta and PyPy3.5 v7.0.0 fail with the message "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)". My web research indicates that 0xc000007b may be caused by a 32bit app trying to load a 64bit DLL, which seems possible for the 32bit Windows version of PyPy. But even if I could find the offending DLL, what can I do about it? Is there a way to tell pypy3.exe to replace a specific DLL?

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: Why the down vote? I can't change my behavior in the future if I don't know why I'm getting dinged.

Answer (score 0):

"It works for me" is not a very good answer even when it's true.  Maybe you can use the tools described in [How to check for DLL dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378959/how-to-check-for-dll-dependency)

Comment: I used the Dependency app mentioned in that link to check the dependencies. The only occurrence of "64" that I can find is C:\Windows\SysWOW64, e.g. C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\kernelbase.dll. But I installed the same version of PyPy on a Windows 10 Pro system, and it runs with no errors, even though it also has dependencies on the same DLLs in SysWOW64. (btw, I don't understand your reference to "It works for me")