# Finding/Resolving dependent DLLs of a DLL using Java

Tags: java, windows, dll, dllimport, portable-executable

I want to figure out which dependent `DLL`s are missing when loading a `DLL` fails. By loading a `DLL` using `Java`'s [`System#loadLibrary`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)), I only get a long negative exit code such as `-1073741515` instead of a Windows error message stating which `DLL` is missing. This is unhelpful for addressing the problem.

My idea was to parse dependent `DLL`s from the `DLL` using `Java` and loading them one by one to figure out which one throws an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`. I found a library called [`pecoff4j`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.whitesource/pecoff4j) which claims to parse [`PE` executables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Windows_Executable_Files) but I'm not able to parse the imported `DLL` names:

```
PE pe = PEParser.parse("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\my.dll");
final ImportDirectory importTable = pe.getImageData().getImportTable();
for (int i = 0; i < importTable.size(); i++)
{
    String name = importTable.getName(i);
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

This yields the following exception since the names don't seem to be available:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at org.boris.pecoff4j.ImportDirectory.getName(ImportDirectory.java:39)
```

[image]

`ImportDirectory.java`:

```
package org.boris.pecoff4j;

import org.boris.pecoff4j.util.DataObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ImportDirectory extends DataObject {
    private List<ImportDirectoryEntry> entries = new ArrayList();
    private List<String> names = new ArrayList();
    private List<ImportDirectoryTable> nameTables = new ArrayList();
    private List<ImportDirectoryTable> addressTables = new ArrayList();

    public void add(ImportDirectoryEntry entry) {
        entries.add(entry);
    }

    public void add(String name, ImportDirectoryTable names,
            ImportDirectoryTable addresses) {
        this.names.add(name);
        nameTables.add(names);
        addressTables.add(addresses);
    }

    public int size() {
        return entries.size();
    }

    public String getName(int index) {
        return names.get(index);
    }

    public ImportDirectoryTable getNameTable(int index) {
        return nameTables.get(index);
    }

    public ImportDirectoryTable getAddressTable(int index) {
        return addressTables.get(index);
    }

    public ImportDirectoryEntry getEntry(int index) {
        return entries.get(index);
    }
}
```

[`Visual Studio`'s `dumpbin` works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28304716/3764804) but I need a `Java` based solution to integrate into an application which is distributed to users who don't necessarily have `Visual Studio` installed.

If you think there is a better/simpler way to figure out or prevent missing `DLL`s when loading a `DLL` using `Java`, feel free to let me know as well.

Comment: It looks like the method `ImportDirectory.size()` does not give the correct size of the actual list size of names. The ArrayList of Names is not in sync. To tell more, we would need to see the code of the Class ImportDirectory.

Comment: @Sunchezz: Yeah, they're not in sync. I added the class to the question.

Comment: You never add something to the list entries, but in the method size() you are asking for the size of the list entries, which is always 0.

Comment: My Bad... there is a method which adds entries. but, if this one is called, no names are added to the names list.