# How to get DLL missing error feedback for Visual C++ command line projects?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll

I'm building a `Visual C++` executable. The `Release` output folder contains the `EXE` and the dependent `DLL`s. However, if I rename one of the `DLL`s and run the `EXE`, the `EXE` will fail load with exit code `-1073741515` (`0xC0000135`) which means `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`. This is expected, however the cause for the load failure is non-transparent to the user since the `EXE` will just silently "crash" and not generate a helpful error message such as `The DLL xyz.dll was missing`. Some end users might genuinely miss a `DLL` or a [`Visual C++ Redistributable`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0) installation which makes debugging the problem hard.

Is there any way to tell the `Windows` application loader to provide an error message pop-up with diagnostics as to why the `EXE` failed to run properly? I have full control over the `Visual Studio` project settings and the source code. My project is configured as a command line application though if that could be the cause for no graphical loading failure feedback.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58506187) is a related question for a similar issue when running an `EXE` from `Java`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366433/createprocess-status-dll-not-found-which-dll

Comment: Step #1: Use delay-loading.  Step #2: Install a delay-load handler/hook.  Unfortunately this won't work for the C runtime library itself since the compiler support for delay-load assumes the C runtime is available.

Comment: Approach #2: Move all your application code that uses the C runtime to a DLL.  Turn the EXE into a tiny shim that manually loads your application logic DLL, handling loading and error checking using only the Win32 API and no standard C calls.  Some versions of the CRT can't be manually loaded, but you could always manually load a "probe" DLL that takes care to depend on the CRT and nothing else.

Comment: [Linker support for delay-loaded DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls). That allows your application to display additional information. The system won't show anything more useful than the exit code.

Comment: *"Some end users might genuinely miss a `DLL` or a `Visual C++ Redistributable` installation"* - That sounds odd. If your code relies on the Visual C++ Redistributable, then your installer is required to install it. You cannot just ship your code and hope for dependencies to be there.

Comment: Thanks guys, I decided to implement delay loading and a delay load failure hook. That works quite well. :)
Also I can statically link the runtime to avoid this problem. I'm not making an installer but I'm distributing the `EXE` with `DLL`s manually as part of another application written in `Java`.