# How to get rid of exit code=3221225781 ,when I run my C++ program on VS code?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, visual-studio-code, exit-code

As I mentioned above I cant run my code succesfully.
is there any thing I can change in my settins inorder to run my programme ?

sorry, if my question dont make sense.____I am a beginner ____

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": ["-g", "${file}", "-o", "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I am unable Debug even!

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
          {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
          }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: [3221225781 decoder](https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=3221225781)

Comment: Which probably means your mingw binary folder is not in the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error means your program can not find some dlls

use ***strace yourprogram*** to see which dlls you need

you can reference this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378959/how-to-check-for-dll-dependency/33019173#33019173)

Comment: Better than `strace` for the purpose of discovering needed libraries would be `ldd`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl  yes, ldd is good. but think this situation: your program need some dlls, and these dlls may still need other dlls, strace can tell which dll is missing "now"