# Failed to import pybind11 modules when linking Eigen with OpenBlas (VS19)

Tags: eigen, pybind11, openblas

Having built openblas (with this method https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/How-to-use-OpenBLAS-in-Microsoft-Visual-Studio) I now have the folders `opt/include` and `opt/lib`. Whereby within `opt/lib` there is a single `openblas.lib` file.

The Eigen docs say to write `#define EIGEN_USE_BLAS` before including any Eigen headers. All my Eigen headers are written in a single `base.h` file to which other headers will have `#include "base.h"`.
Thus, `#define EIGEN_USE_BLAS` is written once in file `base.h`.

- Before I linked with openblas, my project compiled fine and i was able to import my modules etc.

After (only) including the `opt/lib` directory in `Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories` and writing `openblas.lib` in `Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`

- My project compiles successfully as well
- However when trying to import the .pyd files, it says my modules are undefined

Therefore,

- Did I even install `openblas` correctly?, as in is there only supposed to be a single `openblas.lib` file or am i missing something?
- Are my steps in linking my project with openblas correct?

Note:

The modules that wont import have usage of `Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver`

Comment: Could you check the dependencies of your .pyd file (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378959/how-to-check-for-dll-dependency) and check that there are no dynamic libraries you miss? Pasting the exact error you get while doing the import would be helpful as well.

Comment: Hi, It turns out that I compiled OpenBlas with the wrong compiler(?), So i initially followed the steps of `Section 1: Native (MSVC) ABI` which compiles with an LLVM compiler structure. So i tried again following `CMake and Visual Studio` and it works now.